# ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s) in a trigger

Tags: mysql

```
MariaDB [final]> delimiter //
MariaDB [final]> create or replace trigger llena_factura
-> after insert on D_FACTURA
-> FOR EACH ROW
-> BEGIN
-> set @precio=(SELECT * from ARTICULOS where Clave_A=NEW.Clave_A);
-> set @sub=NEW.Cantidad*@precio.Precio_V;
-> set @tot=@sub+NEW.Importe;
-> insert into FACTURA values(NULL,CURDATE(), @sub, @tot,1);
-> END;
-> //
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

```
MariaDB [final]> delimiter ;
MariaDB [final]> insert into D_FACTURA values(5.00,10.00,1);
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

why?
Could you explain to me what is the error in the trigger?

Comment: Without knowing the schema, this `set @precio=(SELECT * from ARTICULOS where Clave_A=NEW.Clave_A);` looks problematic. You cannot set one variable to a resultset that has multiple fields (or multiple results).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL variables are *scalars*, which means they can contain only one value, not a row.

You can't set a variable to the result of `SELECT * ...`

Nor can you access fields of a variable like `@precio.Precio_V`. There are no fields. The variable has only one value.

It looks like you're only using one field from that subquery anyway, so you could set the variable to one column, one row this way:

```
SELECT Precio_V INTO @precio FROM ARTICULOS WHERE Clave_A = NEW.Clave_A LIMIT 1;
SET @sub = NEW.Cantidad * @precio;
```